# How to separate workflows depending on text reply (same-session text reply?)

Tags: php, twilio, twilio-php

We are currently integrating Twilio + Unbounce using Stamplay.

Our current set up is that upon completion of a contact form, the Agent receives a call from the Twilio number, and shortly after receives a text notifying them of a lead.

Our ideal situation would be to create a workflow whereby upon completion of a contact form, an Agent will receive an SMS with the details of the contact, but NOT be called prior to this SMS (perhaps a second Twilio number would be required to receive the call, which would then trigger the text to the Agent).

We then want the Agent to then be able to send a text in this immediate session with either "Yes" or "Later" when asked if they would like to connect with the contact immediately.

If the Agent says "Yes", then the Agent would be connected with the number of the Lead. If the Agent says "No", then the Agent would receive a text in X hours with a notification SMS reminding them to contact XYZ lead.

We use PHP and if you could provide some advice as to some of the main verbs/nouns that would be required, would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

P.S.

What we have so far:
This TWIML bin gets called upon conclusion of call to Agent (configured in Stamplay),

```
https://handler.twilio.com/twiml/example?leadNum={{2wQE.lead.body.data.phone_number.[0]}}&leadName={{2wQE.lead.body.data.name.[0]}}
```

This SMS gets sent to Agent,

```
<Response>
  <Sms to="+16041234567">You have a new lead. Name:{{leadName}}, with cell: {{leadNum}}. If you want to contact this lead now, reply with 'Yes', otherwise 'Later'.</Sms>

</Response>
```

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I've not worked directly with Stamplay yet, but here's what I think you need to do.

Instead of generating a call when the form is submitted, you should just generate an SMS message to the Agent. You'll need to store the details of the request in a database somehow too.

Then you'll need another action to receive an incoming SMS message. If the message says "yes" (you'll need what I think is called a code block for this), you would look up the last form submission data from the database and then generate the call to the agent and then connect it to the customer. If the message says "no" then you'll want to schedule the reminder later.

You could also achieve this using PHP and the [Twilio REST API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest) for generating calls and messages.

For Stamplay, this [blog post might help with the Twilio interactions and storing details in the database](https://blog.stamplay.com/build-a-daily-news-by-sms-service-with-twilio-and-scheduled-flows-fb80dd3f8abd).

Let me know if this helps at all.